# strace hwinfo --dump-db 0 does not dump to /var/lib/hardware

Tags: command-line, hardware

According to the man page of `hwinfo` this command should dump to /var/lib/hardware.

```
hwinfo --dump-db 0
```

But on my Ubuntu server the above command seems to do nothing.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Version:

```
root@foo:~# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hwinfo/+bug/1657544) in Ubuntu Launchpad for 16.10 not saving configuration files.

In summary the debian version wasn't creating the directories:

```
DIR PERMISSION
/var/lib/hardware 0755
/var/lib/hardware/udi 0755
```

I tried creating these directories manually after installing `hwinfo` but the command to dump the database still wouldn't work for me.

I suggest filing a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the 16.04 `hwinfo` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/hwinfo.8.html):

```
--dump-db N
      Dump hardware data base. N is either 0  for  the  external  data
      base in /var/lib/hardware, or 1 for the internal data base.

...
FILES

/var/lib/hardware/hd.ids
      External hardware data base (in readable  text  form).  Try  the
      --dump-db option to see the format.

/var/lib/hardware/udi
      Directory  where  persistent config data are stored (see --save-
      config option).
```

I read that as `hwinfo` dumping **from** the database in `/var/lib/hardware`, not dumping **to** `/var/lib/hardware`. So if there's nothing in `/var/lib/hardware`, there's nothing to dump.

And the `strace` output reflects this:

```
$ strace -e open hwinfo --dump-db 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhd.so.21", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx86emu.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/version", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/proc/cmdline", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/var/lib/hardware/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/modules.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/var/lib/hardware/hd.ids", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/lib/hardware/ids", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

It tries (and fails) to **read** `/var/lib/hardware/hd.ids`.

Comment: You said "It tries (and fails) to read /var/lib/hardware/hd.ids". What does this mean? Is the software broken, or is the directory structure broken?

Comment: It means that that file doesn't exist on my system. I don't think it implies anything is broken.

Comment: I am a stupid end user. I don't see the expected result. I could use many names for this: strange, broken, magic, ...

Comment: @guettli what result did you expect?

Comment: @guettli, change the 0 in your commandto 1 & you'll see the difference in results..